# Can't include a Google Maps marker in code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-animate

Here's what I've been working on: http://jsfiddle.net/sumeetbansal/morxcuxc/.

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.291, 53.027),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

el = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
var map = new google.maps.Map(el,mapOptions);

// Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
// supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.

var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
    };

var start = new google.maps.LatLng (32.291, 3.027);
var endpt = new google.maps.LatLng (12.291, 103.027);
var coord = [start, endpt];
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: coord,
    strokeColor: '#393',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    geodesic: true,
    map: map,
    icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: '100%'
    }],
});

animateCircle();
var step = 0;
var numSteps = 250; //Change this to set animation resolution
var timePerStep = 1; //Change this to alter animation speed
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    step += 1;
    if (step > numSteps) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        var theMotion = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start,endpt,step/numSteps);
        line.setPath([start, theMotion]);
    }
  }, timePerStep);
}

function animateCircle() {
    var count = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        count = (count + 1) % 200;
        var icons = line.get('icons');
        icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
        line.set('icons', icons);
        }, 20);
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I formed it from snippets of other code I found on animating polylines and animating symbols, and it works well enough. However, whenever I try to add a marker to the code (and I tried added it in numerous places), the code never initializes, sometimes not showing anything and at other times showing only the map. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
var sourceImage = 'source-map-marker.png';
new mrker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: start,
    map: map,
    icon: sourceImage
    });
```

Comment: Did you look at the javascript console for errors?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `new` before `mrker` and replace by `var`:
`var mrker = new google.maps.Marker({`

See : http://jsfiddle.net/yghoy4ka/